# i want to decrease the quantity field and decrease its number

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.IssueBook
    (
    @bookid nvarchar(50),
    @ano nvarchar(50),
    @mid int,
    @librarian varchar(10),
    @quantity int
    )
AS
    declare @cnt int
    declare @msg varchar(100)
    if  not exists( select * from books where bookid = @bookid and quantity = @quantity) 
       begin
         raiserror('Book is not available',16,1);      
         return;
       end;


    select @cnt = count(bookid) from issues where mid = @mid;
    if ( @cnt >= 2 )   
        begin
         raiserror('Maximum Limit Has Been Reached For Member!',16,1);
         return;
       end;

    begin tran
    begin try 
      update books set quantity =@quantity-1 where bookid= @bookid;
      insert into issues values (@bookid, @mid, getdate(), @librarian, @ano);
      commit tran
    end try
    begin catch
         rollback tran
         /* select  @msg = error_message() */
         raiserror( 'Unknown Error', 16,1);
    end catch
```

i want to change value of `quantity` field in sql table how can i do that please help me i tried many things but they are not working i will be very thankful to you...

Comment: It looks like the @quantity should not be a parameter at all, you could just fetch it from the table in the beginning when you're checking availability -- and you should just have update ... quantity = quantity -1 without the variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this part: `set quantity =@quantity-1`. If I understand you correctly, it should either be

```
set quantity = quantity-1 -- Decreease the book quantity by 1
```

or

```
set quantity = quantity - @quantity -- Decreease the book quantity by @quantity
```

Comment: hi  try this but its not working its giving me error "The method or operation is not implemented."

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an sql exception. Please edit your question to include the code and exception.